# javascript - merge, combine, transform 2 different arrays of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I can't figure it out how to transform and combine 2 arrays of object.

I have this 2 arrays of objects:

```
const selectedCourse = [
    {
      "courseType": [5],
      "id": 26,
      "title": "Apple Tart with Apricot Glaze",
  },
  {
    "courseType": [3],
    "id": 16,
    "title": "Classic Caesar Salad",
},
{
  "courseType": [1,2],
  "id": 10,
  "title": "Lobster Bisque",
},
{
  "courseType": [3],
  "id": 16,
  "title": "Classic Caesar Salad",
},
]

const courseTypes = [
{name: "Hors d'oeuvres", id: 0},
 {name: "Soup", id: 1},
 {name: "Fish", id: 2},
 {name: "Salad", id: 3},
 {name: "Main course", id: 4},
 {name: "Dessert", id: 5}
]
```

The **courseType** property inside the first JSON  is an array of numbers that corresponds to **courseTypes** index and property **id** in the second JSON.

The result for this case should be this:

```
const result = [
  {
    courseType: 1,
    courseName: "Soup",
    courses: [
      {
        "courseType": [1,2],
        "id": 10,
        "title": "Lobster Bisque",
      }      
    ]
  },
  {
    courseType: 3,
    courseName: "Salad",
    courses: [
      {
        "courseType": [1,2],
        "id": 10,
        "title": "Lobster Bisque",
      }      
    ]
  },
  {
    courseType: 3,
    courseName: "Fish",
    courses: [
      {
        "courseType": [3],
        "id": 16,
        "title": "Classic Caesar Salad",
      },
      {
        "courseType": [3],
        "id": 16,
      },      
    ]
  },
  {
    courseType: 5,
    courseName: "Main course",
    courses: [
      {
        "courseType": [5],
        "id": 26,
        "title": "Apple Tart with Apricot Glaze",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The expected result have to combine the 2 arrays by filtering by **courseType** property.

Comment: on the second Object inside "result" the "courseType" property is equal to 2

Comment: When I read the first paragraph I thought "Great! At last someone who does not call a JavaScript object JSON". Too bad it entered in the second paragraph...

Comment: Your expected output has `courseType: 3, courseName: "Fish"` I suppose that is a typo, since Fish has an id 2 in your input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `map` and `filter` like this:

```js
const selectedCourse = [ { "courseType": [5], "id": 26, "title": "Apple Tart with Apricot Glaze", }, { "courseType": [3], "id": 16, "title": "Classic Caesar Salad", }, { "courseType": [1,2], "id": 10, "title": "Lobster Bisque", }, { "courseType": [3], "id": 16, "title": "Classic Caesar Salad", }, ]

const courseTypes = [ {name: "Hors d'oeuvres", id: 0}, {name: "Soup", id: 1}, {name: "Fish", id: 2}, {name: "Salad", id: 3}, {name: "Main course", id: 4}, {name: "Dessert", id: 5} ];

const result = courseTypes.map(courseType => ({
    courseType: courseType.id, 
    courseName: courseType.name,
    courses: selectedCourse.filter(course => course.courseType.includes(courseType.id))
})).filter(extended => extended.courses.length);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

#### Explanation:

`courseTypes.map` iterates over your second input array and for each type it finds in `selectedCourse` which courses match with that particular type.

It uses `.filter` to collect those matches. The `filter` callback uses `includes` to determine if there is a match -- it returns a boolean, exactly what the filter callback expects as return value.

This filtered array is then added to an object literal that also defines the other two properties `courseType` and `courseName`. That new object is what the course type is mapped to. `courseTypes.map` returns an array of those objects.

Finally that result may have entries that have an empty `courses` array. Those are filtered out with another call to `.filter`. If the `length` of that `courses` array is non zero, the object is kept, otherwise it is kicked out of the result.

#### For older browsers

Here is the same code made compatible with older browsers (no arrow functions, no `includes`, which were introduced in ES2015):

```js
const selectedCourse = [ { "courseType": [5], "id": 26, "title": "Apple Tart with Apricot Glaze", }, { "courseType": [3], "id": 16, "title": "Classic Caesar Salad", }, { "courseType": [1,2], "id": 10, "title": "Lobster Bisque", }, { "courseType": [3], "id": 16, "title": "Classic Caesar Salad", }, ]

const courseTypes = [ {name: "Hors d'oeuvres", id: 0}, {name: "Soup", id: 1}, {name: "Fish", id: 2}, {name: "Salad", id: 3}, {name: "Main course", id: 4}, {name: "Dessert", id: 5} ];

const result = courseTypes.map(function (courseType) {
    return {
        courseType: courseType.id, 
        courseName: courseType.name,
        courses: selectedCourse.filter(function (course) {
            return course.courseType.indexOf(courseType.id) > -1;
        })
    };
}).filter(function (extended) {
    return extended.courses.length;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: Good solution but I need to display in result only the courseTypes that contains courses, so if the length is 0 it shouldn't be displayed. As you can see in my example :)

Comment: Have you seen the update I posted before you made the comment? I also added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you want all items with `selectedCourse`, you could take a `Map` and collect all courses and later greate a new array out of the found values.

This solution includes *Fish* as well.

```js
const
    selectedCourse = [{ courseType: [5], id: 26, title: "Apple Tart with Apricot Glaze" }, { courseType: [3], id: 16, title: "Classic Caesar Salad" }, { courseType: [1, 2], id: 10, title: "Lobster Bisque" }, { courseType: [3], id: 16, title: "Classic Caesar Salad" }],
    courseTypes = [{ name: "Hors d'oeuvres", id: 0 }, { name: "Soup", id: 1 }, { name: "Fish", id: 2 }, { name: "Salad", id: 3 }, { name: "Main course", id: 4 }, { name: "Dessert", id: 5 }],
    map = selectedCourse.reduce((m, o) => o.courseType.reduce((n, id) => n.set(id, [...(n.get(id) || []), o]), m), new Map),
    result = courseTypes.reduce(
        (r, { name: courseName, id: courseType }) => (map.get(courseType) || []).reduce((s, courses) => s.concat({ courseType, courseName, courses }), r),
        []
    );
   
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Good answer as always :)

Answer (score 0):

while "trincot" code is work fine for chrome and Mozila but it will not work in IE edge and IE 10 and below you need to convert it in pure javascript. below is code which will work in all browser.

```
if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
   Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'includes', {
   value: function(searchElement, fromIndex) {

  if (this == null) {
    throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
  }

  // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
  var o = Object(this);

  // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
  var len = o.length >>> 0;

  // 3. If len is 0, return false.
  if (len === 0) {
    return false;
  }

  // 4. Let n be ? ToInteger(fromIndex).
  //    (If fromIndex is undefined, this step produces the value 0.)
  var n = fromIndex | 0;

  // 5. If n ≥ 0, then
  //  a. Let k be n.
  // 6. Else n < 0,
  //  a. Let k be len + n.
  //  b. If k < 0, let k be 0.
  var k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

  function sameValueZero(x, y) {
    return x === y || (typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number' && isNaN(x) && isNaN(y));
  }

  // 7. Repeat, while k < len
  while (k < len) {
    // a. Let elementK be the result of ? Get(O, ! ToString(k)).
    // b. If SameValueZero(searchElement, elementK) is true, return true.
    if (sameValueZero(o[k], searchElement)) {
      return true;
    }
    // c. Increase k by 1. 
    k++;
  }

  // 8. Return false
  return false;
    }
  });
}
var selectedCourse = [{ "courseType": [5], "id": 26, "title": "Apple Tart with Apricot Glaze" }, { "courseType": [3], "id": 16, "title": "Classic Caesar Salad" }, { "courseType": [1, 2], "id": 10, "title": "Lobster Bisque" }, { "courseType": [3], "id": 16, "title": "Classic Caesar Salad" }];
var courseTypes = [{ name: "Hors d'oeuvres", id: 0 }, { name: "Soup", id: 1 }, { name: "Fish", id: 2 }, { name: "Salad", id: 3 }, { name: "Main course", id: 4 }, { name: "Dessert", id: 5 }];
var result = courseTypes.map(function (courseType) {
return {
    courseType: courseType.id,
    courseName: courseType.name,
    courses: selectedCourse.filter(function (course) {
        return course.courseType.includes(courseType.id);
    })
  };
}).filter(function (extended) {
   return extended.courses.length;
});

 console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: What do you mean with "above code"? Note that answers are sorted by user settings, so saying "above" does not make a lot of sense. It is better to make such comments under the answers themselves, in the form of a comment ;-)

Comment: You seem to suggest that Edge does not support `includes`, but it does. NB: "IE edge" is not a thing. It is either IE or Edge.