# select data from two different arrays of objects to create a new array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following arrays of objects:

```
const formulas =
[
    { "formulaID": "1", "versionID": 1, "formulaClass": 3, "formulaType": "34", "outputName": "Chocolate Milk 2%" },
    { "formulaID": "4", "versionID": 1, "formulaClass": 3, "formulaType": "17", "outputName": "Hazelnut Creamer" },
    { "formulaID": "6", "versionID": 1, "formulaClass": 3, "formulaType": "23", "outputName": "White Milk 2%" }
];

const yields =
[
    { "formulaID": "4", "versionID": 1, "yieldFactor": 0.93 },
    { "formulaID": "4", "versionID": 2, "yieldFactor": 0.98 },
    { "formulaID": "6", "versionID": 1, "yieldFactor": 0.95 },
    { "formulaID": "7", "versionID": 1, "yieldFactor": 0.85 }
];
```

and am trying to programmatically create this output:

```
const result =
[
    { "formulaID": "7", "versionID": 1, "yieldFactor": 0.85, "outputName": "" },
    { "formulaID": "4", "versionID": 1, "yieldFactor": 0.93, "outputName": "Hazelnut Creamer" },
    { "formulaID": "4", "versionID": 2, "yieldFactor": 0.98, "outputName": "" },
    { "formulaID": "6", "versionID": 1, "yieldFactor": 0.95, "outputName": "White Milk 2%" }
];
```

With the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52700888/javascript-merge-combine-transform-2-different-arrays-of-objects) I wrote this code:

```
const result = yields.map(yld => ({
    formulaID: yld.formulaID,
    versionID: yld.versionID,
    yieldFactor: yld.yieldFactor,
    outputName: formulas.filter(f => (f.formulaID + '-' + f.versionID).includes(yld.formulaID + '-' + yld.versionID))
}));

console.log(result);
```

It is close to the desired outcome but I'm not sure how to isolate just the `outputName`.  In its current state it's giving the entire array where a match is found.  How do I display only the `outputName` for matches and an empty string for `outputName` where there is no match between the original arrays of source data?

**Edit -**
The current output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: what is your current output?

Comment: Try: `yields.map(yld => ({...yld, outputName: (formulas.find(f => f.formulaID === yld.formulaID && f.versionID === yld.versionID) || {}).outputName});`

Comment: @Titus - would you consider posting this comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.filter` will always return an array of formulas satisfying your condition, so you need to check if it gave results first, then retrieve only `.outputName` from its results.

Could be something like this:

```
const result = yields.map(yld => {
  const targetFormulas = formulas.filter(f => (f.formulaID + '-' + f.versionID).includes(yld.formulaID + '-' + yld.versionID));
  const outputName = targetFormulas.length ? targetFormulas.map(f => f.outputName).join(',') : ''
  return {
    formulaID: yld.formulaID,
    versionID: yld.versionID,
    yieldFactor: yld.yieldFactor,
    outputName
  }
});
```

I've used a `.join(',')` to return outputNames separated by comma, if there are more than 1.
If you're sure that only 1 will be returned, you can do 
`targetFormulas.map(f => f.outputName)[0]`

This will return the following result

```
[
   {
      "formulaID":"4",
      "versionID":1,
      "yieldFactor":0.93,
      "outputName":"Hazelnut Creamer"
   },
   {
      "formulaID":"4",
      "versionID":2,
      "yieldFactor":0.98,
      "outputName":""
   },
   {
      "formulaID":"6",
      "versionID":1,
      "yieldFactor":0.95,
      "outputName":"White Milk 2%"
   },
   {
      "formulaID":"7",
      "versionID":1,
      "yieldFactor":0.85,
      "outputName":""
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `reduce` method with `Map` collection to have `O(1)` while mapping elements:

```
const uniqueUtems = new Map(formulas.map(s=>[s.formulaID, s.outputName]));

const result = yields.reduce((a, {formulaID, ...rest}) => {
    a.push({ formulaID , outputName: uniqueUtems.get(formulaID) || '', ...rest });
    if (uniqueUtems.has(formulaID))
        uniqueUtems.delete(formulaID)
    return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

An example:

```js
const formulas =
[
    { "formulaID": "1", "versionID": 1, "formulaClass": 3, "formulaType": "34", "outputName": "Chocolate Milk 2%" },
    { "formulaID": "4", "versionID": 1, "formulaClass": 3, "formulaType": "17", "outputName": "Hazelnut Creamer" },
    { "formulaID": "6", "versionID": 1, "formulaClass": 3, "formulaType": "23", "outputName": "White Milk 2%" }
];

const yields =
[
    { "formulaID": "4", "versionID": 1, "yieldFactor": 0.93 },
    { "formulaID": "4", "versionID": 2, "yieldFactor": 0.98 },
    { "formulaID": "6", "versionID": 1, "yieldFactor": 0.95 },
    { "formulaID": "7", "versionID": 1, "yieldFactor": 0.85 }
];

const uniqueUtems = new Map(formulas.map(s=>[s.formulaID, s.outputName]));

const result = yields.reduce((a, {formulaID, ...rest}) => {
    a.push({ formulaID , outputName: uniqueUtems.get(formulaID) || '', ...rest });
    if (uniqueUtems.has(formulaID))
        uniqueUtems.delete(formulaID)
    return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

[`...rest` is:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

> The rest parameter syntax allows us to represent an indefinite number
>   of arguments as an array.

Comment: What is `...rest`?

Comment: Also, does this solution account for the 2 properties, `formulaID` and `versionID`, that make up the key for each object?

Comment: This does not give the correct result for `formulaID` = 4 which has 2 different `versionID`s.  It is populating the `outputName` for both versionIDs of this `formulaID` but it should only populate it for `versionID` = 1.

Comment: @knot22 ooops, I've edited my reply. Please, see my updated reply. Thanks!